# Why cannot find argument in nest.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, nestjs

When I develop `API` by `nestjs`, I suffered following `errors`.

It seems argument must be defined.

Here is my `controller.ts`

```
  @Get()
    getdata(@Query() query: { place: string}){
    return this.eventService.getEvent(place);
  }
```

Here is my `service.ts`

```
  async getEvent(eventPlace: string): Promise<any>{
    const event = await this.eventRepository
    .find({
      where: {
        place: eventPlace,
      },
    });
```

Here is my `error`

```
src/event/event.controller.ts:24:39 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'place'.

24     return this.eventService.getEvent(place);
                                         ~~~~~

[4:15:34 AM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

Why this argument cannot be found ?

I set argument in `getdata` function.
If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Not super familiar with TS, but try query.place.

Comment: Agree with upper comment - need to get query['place']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Query` decorator lets you extract a specific key. You can just define your controller like this to get a better experience:

```js
@Get()
getdata(@Query('place') place: string) {
    return this.eventService.getEvent(place);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Jesse's answer, you could use object deconstructing and do something similar like

```js
@Get()
getData(@Query() { place }: { place: string }) {
  return this.eventService.getEvent(place);
}
```

This is useful when you want to validate an entire DTO, but only need some of the fields from it.